# How would I react to a specific message in [discord.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make my bot react to a specific message in a channel. This is the code I have so far:

```
message.fetch(`messageID`).then(message => {
  message.react(`emoji`);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch a specific message you must at least fetch it's channel before :

```js
message.client.channels.fetch("channelID").then(channel => {
    channel.messages.fetch("messageID").then(message => {
        message.react("emoji");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not working, I keep getting the error code: ReferenceError: client is not defined

Comment: Oh so you mean the code you show in your question is literally all you write in your file? `client` is the var you use to store the instance of `Discord.Client`

Comment: I'll need full code to help you more, at least main file where the Discord.Client is instantiated and the related command file.

Comment: Alright, in your command file, just add `message` in front of client. I edit my answer to show you.

Comment: Is there anyway to fetch the channel that the command was sent in?

Comment: Yes, in your command file code the `message` var is currently having a `channel` property ([see documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=channel))

Answer (score -1):

```
bot.on('message', message=>{
  message.bot.channels.fetch("channelID").then(channel => {
    channel.messages.fetch("messageID").then(message => {
        message.react(emoji);
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: You really should add some content with your answer. Explain why your code works, what is going on with the what you have provided. Try to walk the OP through what you have provided in your code. Answers with no comments will always be flagged *low-quality*