# React to fetched messages with Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have written a command with which the bot should react to another message. The command is reacted to, the code is correct as far as it goes, but this is what comes from the bot:

```
TypeError: msg.react is not a function
```

Is this not possible from the API, or is the code wrong?

Code:

```
    if (message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_CHANNELS')) {
        const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(' ');
        const messages = args[1]
        const emoji = args[2]

        const msg = message.channel.messages.fetch(messages)
        msg.react(emoji)
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to react to every message ever sent with discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56937895/is-there-a-way-to-react-to-every-message-ever-sent-with-discord-js)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would I react to a specific message in discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61920693/how-would-i-react-to-a-specific-message-in-discord-js)

Answer (score 0):

[`messages.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) returns a promise so you need to resolve it first:

```js
message.channel.messages.fetch(messages)
  .then(msg => msg.react(emoji))
```

Or you can use `await`:

```js
const msg = await message.channel.messages.fetch(messages)
msg.react(emoji)
```